# How do I delete all the DATA from a Column in SQL?

Tags: sql

```html
ShipperID ShipperName        Phone
1         Speedy Express    (503) 555-9831
2         United Package    (503) 555-3199
3         Federal Shipping   (503) 555-9931
```

For example, if I want to delete all of data from column 'ShipperName' but not the entire column from the table so that it could look like this:

```html
ShipperID ShipperName        Phone
1                           (503) 555-9831
2                           (503) 555-3199
3                           (503) 555-9931
```

how would i do that? Or is there a way to just make all the data to NULL such as:

```html
ShipperID ShipperName        Phone
1         NULL              (503) 555-9831
2         NULL              (503) 555-3199
3         NULL              (503) 555-9931
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `update`:

```
update t
    set ShipperName = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following syntax replace with your column and table and where condition is optional

> ```
> UPDATE table_name
> SET column1=NULL
> WHERE some_column=some_value
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Assuming Table Name is Shipper
UPDATE Shipper SET ShipperName = ''
```

Comment: Hi Andy3B, this answer was already posted 3 minutes ago by Gordon. You could add a comment to that answer indicating that you came up with that answer as well.

Comment: I don't think is the same answer. 1. Gordon SET to NULL. 2. Gordon uses an Alias "t" of a missing Table.

Comment: This is a great example of why it's useful to provide an explanation instead of just code—and _especially_ when there are other answers already. Why is this approach preferable over e.g. Gordon's? This is a good opportunity to educate readers about your proposal.